# Replacing NULL values when selecting from an excel spreadsheet

Tags: sql, asp-classic

I have the following select statement:

```
`Dim rsGetInvoiceContact
 Dim rsGetInvoiceContact_numRows

 Set rsGetInvoiceContact = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
 rsGetInvoiceContact.ActiveConnection = MM_conn_to_EFACs_STRING_ap
 rsGetInvoiceContact.Source = "SELECT *   from "& ActinicPersons &" p  WHERE p.[Contact          ID] = " + Replace(rsGetInvoiceContact__vInvoiceID, "'", "''") + "" 
 rsGetInvoiceContact.CursorType = 0
 rsGetInvoiceContact.CursorLocation = 2
 rsGetInvoiceContact.LockType = 1
 rsGetInvoiceContact.Open()

 rsGetInvoiceContact_numRows = 0

 "& FormatStr(rsGetInvoiceContact.Fields.Item("Address Line 1").Value) + ", " +      (rsGetInvoiceContact.Fields.Item("Address Line 2").Value) &"',`
```

Later on in my script I plus address line 1 with address line 2. The problem occurs when address line 2 has a NULL value. How can I replace that from the select statement so that if only address line 1 has a value, it will still insert into the database rather than leave a blank cell.

Thanks

Comment: This question needs greater clarity.  Not all relevant code is displayed.  The actually work that needs doing is unclear.  More text more code needed.

Comment: The overall aim is to insert the data into an SQL table, here's the current insert code:  '"& FormatStr(rsGetInvoiceContact.Fields.Item("Address Line 1").Value)  + ",  " + (rsGetInvoiceContact.Fields.Item("Address Line 2").Value) &"', however when using that and address line 2 has a NULL the whole plus statement is NULL when I still require address line one to be input

Comment: Please use the questions edit function to include new info there, code is unreadable in a comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you coould either add a where clause like "where addressline2 is not null" 
or
in your script where you plus the address lines use something like this

```
adress = (adress1&"") & (adress2&"")
```

by this you always have a string instead of a null value

Comment: @AnthonyWJones yes seems to work i thought that if one expression is null the whole expression is null but adress1 & adress2 & "" works even if adress2 is null...

Comment: Quite so, you need to think a little more mathematically :)

Comment: SELECT *   from "& ActinicPersons &" p  WHERE p.[Contact          ID] = " + Replace(rsGetInvoiceContact__vInvoiceID, "'", "''") + " and address Line 1 & address Line 2 & """ Should do the trick right?

Answer (score 0):

You can use null handling functions like the MySQL or SqlServer's coalesce() function.

```
adress = coalesce(adress1,"") & coalesce(adress2,"")
```

you can replace the second param with the expected default value.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! Would you put that after the WHERE clause?

Comment: you can put it in your select clause if you need to fetch the data or in your where clause i you want it to be a condition : where (coalesce(adress1,"") & adress2) <> "test"

Comment: if all expressions are null then you still get null better use isnull(adress2, '')

Comment: '' is not null as far as I know ;)